# How to dynamically select different config file against different conditions in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I want to load different config files for different conditions. for example, if I have "vendor" in my variable value, then load a vendor's config file, similarly for ext_warehouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not possible, SSIS will load all the file you specify on the package configuration organizer on the order they are listed and it will use the values on the configuration files to load your variables.

What you could do, lets say you have a "vendors.dtsConfig" and a"customer.dtsConfig", is to create a parent package that read a config file called "parent.dtsConfig" that will only have your variable containing "vendor" or "customer" and based on that value you copy the correct config file to another folder and call the actual package that reads the recently copied (and renamed) file

Comment: Can you please paste the link of some similar example?

Comment: I have created the parent package with the parent config file, and created the variable with its value set to "vendor", now how to copy correct config file to another folder?

Comment: cool, there is a file system task you can use to copy the file from one folder to another. I would change one thing on my answer though, instead of renaming the file, keep the file with the same name but on diferetn folders so if you have "vendor" copy the config file in the vendor folder and if you have customer, copy the file form the customer folder. this way you dont have to rename it

Comment: Do be aware that this approach does not address concurrent access issues-thus process A fires off for Vendor and overlays the shared config file with Vendor values. Process B fires off and overlays shared config with Customer. If the A process's child package has not started before B copies the file, A's running with B's config.

Comment: true, but I would expect that this first step will be really fast so unless the package is run twice in a very small interval he sbhoudlnt have problems. BUt better save than sorry, so yes, I would add a "executionID" control where you can run something like SELECT CAST (@@SPID AS INT) AS ProcessID and create a destination folder with this process ID and do all the destination processing in this folder.  Yet, this solution is becomming overcomplicated, maybe you should add your configs on a sql database and only load "vendor" or "customer" and select from a table based on this value